# Tkinter: Changing value of a Textbox after calculation to avoid duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *


class HHRG:

    def __init__(self, root):

        self.root = root
        self.RnReg = 50
        self.RnResump = 80
        self.RnCert = 80
        self.RnDC = 70
        self.RnSOC = 90

        self.LvnReg = 40
        self.LvnOut = 35

        self.Hha = 25
        self.Pt = 75
        self.Ot = 75
        self.St = 75

        self.HHRGValue = IntVar()
        self.RnRegValue = IntVar()
        self.RnResumpValue = IntVar()
        self.RnCertValue = IntVar()
        self.RnDCValue = IntVar()
        self.RnSOCValue = IntVar()

        self.LvnRegValue = IntVar()
        self.LvnOutValue = IntVar()

        self.HhaValue = IntVar()
        self.PtValue = IntVar()
        self.OtValue = IntVar()
        self.StValue = IntVar()

        ###LABELS###
        self.HHRGLabel = Label(self.root, text="HHRG")
        self.RnRegLabel = Label(self.root, text="Regular Rn Visits")
        self.RnResumpLabel = Label(self.root, text="Rn Resumption Visits")
        self.RnCertLabel = Label(self.root, text="Rn recertification Visits")
        self.RnDCLabel = Label(self.root, text="Rn D/C Visits")
        self.RnSOCLabel = Label(self.root, text="Rn SOC Visits")

        self.LvnRegLabel = Label(self.root, text="Regular Lvn Visits")
        self.LvnOutLabel = Label(self.root, text="Lvn Outlier Visits")

        self.HhaLabel = Label(self.root, text="HHA visits")

        self.PtLabel = Label(self.root, text="Pt Visits")
        self.OtLabel = Label(self.root, text="Ot Visits")
        self.StLabel = Label(self.root, text="St Visits")
        self.TotalLabel = Label(self.root, text="Net Total")

        ###ENTRY BOXES###
        self.HHRGEntry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.HHRGValue)
        self.RnRegEntry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.RnRegValue)
        self.RnResumpEntry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.RnResumpValue)
        self.RnCertEntry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.RnCertValue)
        self.RnDCEntry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.RnDCValue)
        self.RnSOCEntry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.RnSOCValue)

        self.LvnRegEntry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.LvnRegValue)
        self.LvnOutEntry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.LvnOutValue)

        self.HhaEntry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.HhaValue)

        self.PtEntry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.PtValue)
        self.OtEntry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.OtValue)
        self.StEntry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.StValue)
        self.TotalEntry = Text(root, height=2, width=10)

        self.clearButton = Button(root, text="Clear")
        self.clearButton.bind("<Button-1>", self.clear)

        self.calculatebutton = Button(root, text="Calculate", width=10)
        self.calculatebutton.bind("<Button-1>", self.clear)
        self.calculatebutton.bind("<Button-1>", self.calculate)

        ####LABEL GRIDS###
        self.HHRGLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.RnRegLabel.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.RnResumpLabel.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.RnCertLabel.grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.RnDCLabel.grid(row=4, column=0)
        self.RnSOCLabel.grid(row=5, column=0)

        self.LvnRegLabel.grid(row=6, column=0)
        self.LvnOutLabel.grid(row=7, column=0)

        self.HhaLabel.grid(row=8, column=0)

        self.PtLabel.grid(row=9, column=0)
        self.OtLabel.grid(row=10, column=0)
        self.StLabel.grid(row=11, column=0)

        self.TotalLabel.grid(row=12, column=0)

        ###ENTRY GRIDS###
        self.HHRGEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.RnRegEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.RnResumpEntry.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.RnCertEntry.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.RnDCEntry.grid(row=4, column=1)
        self.RnSOCEntry.grid(row=5, column=1)

        self.LvnRegEntry.grid(row=6, column=1)
        self.LvnOutEntry.grid(row=7, column=1)

        self.HhaEntry.grid(row=8, column=1)
        self.PtEntry.grid(row=9, column=1)
        self.OtEntry.grid(row=10, column=1)
        self.StEntry.grid(row=11, column=1)

        self.TotalEntry.grid(row=12, column=1)

        self.calculatebutton.grid(columnspan=2, pady=10)
        self.clearButton.grid(row=13, column=1)

    def calculate(self, event):
        values = [(self.RnRegValue.get() * self.RnReg),
                  (self.RnResumpValue.get() * self.RnResump),
                  (self.RnCertValue.get() * self.RnCert),
                  (self.RnDCValue.get() * self.RnDC),
                  (self.RnSOCValue.get() * self.RnSOC),
                  (self.LvnRegValue.get() * self.LvnReg),
                  (self.LvnOutValue.get() * self.LvnOut),
                  (self.HhaValue.get() * self.Hha),
                  (self.PtValue.get() * self.Pt),
                  (self.OtValue.get() * self.Ot),
                  (self.StValue.get() * self.St)]

        self.total = 0
        for i in values:
            self.total += i

        result = self.HHRGValue.get() - self.total

        self.TotalEntry.insert(END, result)

    def clear(self, event):
        self.TotalEntry.delete("1.0", END)


root = Tk()
a = HHRG(root)
root.mainloop()
```

So i've got this modified calculator of mine and the problem with it is everytime you calculate. it returns outputs as desired but if you click it twice 
it'll duplicate

[image: Duplicated Result]

I tried binding the `self.calculatebutton` to my  `clear()` method but it wouldn't prevent the duplication of the results

my question is. How can we make it calculate the desired output but wipe the previous output at the same time to prevent duplicates? so if someone presses the calculate button multiple times it'll only output one total not multiple ones like the picture above

Comment: Are you simply asking how to reset the variables to zero?

Comment: @BryanOakley I did say output on the question :/ and man so quick to downvote tsk

Comment: The downvote was because the question shows absolutely no sign of you doing any research, and you didn't convert the problem MCVE. You seem to be asking how to clear the value in a widget, which is documented in many places.

Comment: @BryanOakley ugh the clear method is there because it clears the text area of the net value so i know that . What I asked is how do you prevent duplicates of the output in the net value. did you even read the question? or are you so smart you don't understand something as simple as that? I searched for a good hour before posting this on in here. before Shahzad  gave the answer. look I get I you think I didn't do any research but I did and when I couldn't find the answer that's when I asked it in here

Comment: If you searched for a good hour before asking, include that in your question. How are we to know that you've read the tkinter documentation, when the question you're asking seems to be answered by reading the documentation? I can't read your mind, I can only read your question. The down-vote isn't a personal attack on you, it is designed to let you know that your question is of low quality and not particularly useful (useful to you, but not very useful to anybody else who visits this site).

Comment: I always phrase the title of my questions in a general way. to make it reach more people having the same problem while addressing my own. I am never ashamed of admitting that I am a newbie. I just started tkinter yesterday  in fact programming just last month. Im trying my best since I can't provide good answers yet because I am not knowledgeable enough .I try to ask good questions I try to phrase it as general as I could. just look at the answers below they are very informative and not just applying to my case. People would know more about bind etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix could be to just call your `clear` method in your `calculate` method, before inserting the text into your `TotalEntry` text widget.

Try this:

```
def calculate(self,event):
    values = [(self.RnRegValue.get() * self.RnReg),
              (self.RnResumpValue.get() * self.RnResump),
              (self.RnCertValue.get() * self.RnCert),
              (self.RnDCValue.get() * self.RnDC),
              (self.RnSOCValue.get() * self.RnSOC),
              (self.LvnRegValue.get() * self.LvnReg),
              (self.LvnOutValue.get() * self.LvnOut),
              (self.HhaValue.get() * self.Hha),
              (self.PtValue.get() * self.Pt),
              (self.OtValue.get() * self.Ot),
              (self.StValue.get() * self.St)]



    self.total = 0
    for i in values:
        self.total += i

    result = self.HHRGValue.get() - self.total
    self.clear(event)
    self.TotalEntry.insert(END,result)
```

Comment: Hmm you can do that? I didn't know. What I did try initially was bind the clear method and and calculate method on the the calculate button but that didn't do anything which was pretty odd. Will try this

Comment: thank you it worked. I seriously didn't know you could do that. thanks you very much

Comment: why does binding the calculate button to the clear method and calculate method not do the same thing as your fix did?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can only bind one method to the button. Therefore, looking at the order you did it in, the button gets bound to the `clear` method and in the next line it get overriden and gets bound to the `calculate` method. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes it does. I didn't know about that. I'll try to use command more often now

Answer (score 2):

This code is where the problem lies:

```
self.calculatebutton = Button(root,text="Calculate",width=10)
self.calculatebutton.bind("<Button-1>",self.clear)
self.calculatebutton.bind("<Button-1>",self.calculate)
```

When you call `bind`, it will *replace* any previous binding of the same event to the same widget. So, the binding to `self.clear` goes away when you add the binding to `self.calculate`. While there are ways to bind multiple functions to an event, usually that is completely unnecessary and leads to difficult-to-maintain code.

The simple solution is for your calculate function to call the clear function before adding a new result:

```
def calculate(self,event):
    ...
    result = self.HHRGValue.get() - self.total
    self.clear(event=None)
    self.TotalEntry.insert(END,result)
```

Note: if this is the only time you'll call clear, you can remove the `event` parameter from the function definition, and remove it from the call.

On a related note: generally speaking you should *not* use `bind` on buttons. The button has built-in bindings that normally work better than your custom binding (they handle keyboard traversal and button highlighting, for example).

The button widget has a `command` attribute which you normally use instead of a binding. In your case it would look like this:

```
self.calculatebutton = Button(..., command=self.calculate)
```

When you do that, your `calculate` method no longer needs the `event` parameter, so you'll need to remove it. If you want to use the `calculate` function both from a `command` and from a binding, you can make the event optional:

```
def calculate(self, event=None)
```

Comment: thank you for this. I didn't know bind would override any previous binding no wonder why. Ok i'll try to use the command, command more often now. thanks for such an informative answer